# Bootstrap 4 keep nav items inline on screen sizes before collaps

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm rewriting my nav from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4.  In Bootstrap 3, the nav size was responsive and would shrink to fit the space until the set collapse size (see here: https://www.uvm.edu/femc/).  In Bootstrap 4, the li elements start to stack on each other.  I have set the li elements to inline-block as other posts have suggested, but it still doesn't work.

This is what the nav looks like on a medium screen:

[image: Bootstrap 4]

This is what it should look like:
[Bootstrap 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5xua.png)

My code is this:

```
<nav id="toprightnav" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md" role="navigation">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a role="button" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/data" class="headernavli nav-link" >Data</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a role="button" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/monitoring" class="headernavli nav-link" >Monitoring</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/cooperative" class="headernavli nav-link" >Cooperative</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/cooperative">Overview</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/cooperative/regional_projects">Regional Projects</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/cooperative/conference">Conferences</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/cooperative/committees">Committees</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/cooperative/directory">Directory</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/cooperative/join">Join</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/cooperative/orgs">Organizations</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/cooperative/news_events">News/Events</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/products" class="headernavli nav-link" >Products & Services</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/products/tools">Tools</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/products/collections">Collections</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/products/reports">Reports</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/services">Services</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/about" class="headernavli nav-link" >About</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/about">Overview</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/about/staff">Staff</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/about/partnerships">Partnerships</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/about/strategic_plan">Strategic Plan</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/about/contact">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </li>              
            </ul>
          </div>
```

and

```
.nav-link.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b8d87a;
}

.nav-item a:focus {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #b8d87a;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    font-size:small;
    width:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu .nav-link:hover {
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
ul.nav{
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: I checked your website. But, I'm unable to see what you shared in image.

Comment: Because that's the Bootstrap 3 version.  I'm trying to change to Bootstrap 4, which breaks it.  You can see the Bootstrap 4 version here: https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/

Comment: Can you please check your bootstrap 4 version website link?

Comment: Because I got 'This site can't be reached' message

Comment: strange, I just tried 3 different machines and 3 different browsers and they all load it fine.